# Have problem with SSH connection in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I can't connect to my VM instance. "default-allow-ssh" rule in Firewall is "Allow".
I think maybe logs help:

```
Aug 30 09:23:24 my-vm google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 681, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 437, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 372, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Aug 30 09:23:30 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Aug 30 09:23:30 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 15472 (snapd) with signal SIGKILL.
Aug 30 09:23:30 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 30 09:23:30 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 30 09:23:30 my-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 939.
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm snapd[15582]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Aug 30 09:23:31 my-vm snapd[15582]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this is happen because **your disk storage is full**. If you have other type of access to your VM like **connect using Serial console**, check your disk space allocated status through it and try to free up some space or add additional data storage if its full.

Comment: I cant connect to my VM via SSH (In Google panel and from my PC Putty) and I dont know other type of access
I add disk space to my storage but problem isnt solving

Comment: You need to connect using Serial console. check this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: I think @Afshin pointed to right direction just  want to add here [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) might be helpful in this issue specially [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and [Use your disk on a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#move_boot_disk)

Comment: **Thank for this article.
When I nmap to my ip, I see this:**

iamhere@cloudshell:~ (onyx-cosmos-266419)$ nmap **.***.**.**
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-08-31 18:11 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn

                **My VM blocked any connecting right?**

Comment: No problem @МаксимСкладаний 

If you have the firewall for the instance that is open for ingress for the ssh port, usually tcp port 22, the connectivity should not be the issue here. You can check or list the firewall for the instance by following [the document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#listing-rules-vm).

Comment: Lastly, you can add this disk or create an image and then disk from this boot disk and attach this disk to new vm to retrieve the data from there. But i would recommend always take backup ([snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)/[image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images)/[machine image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images)) before attempting any operation you can follow [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance)